# Having problems importing smtplib with Python

Tags: python, email, import, smtplib

When I have a simple python code of:

```
import smtplib
```

I am getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\David\Desktop\email.py", line 25, in <module>
    from smtplib import SMTP_SSL as SMTP       # this invokes the secure SMTP pr
otocol (port 465, uses SSL)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtm
l11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The only explanation would be that your `smtplib.py` somehow got replaced with a html file. Try to open `C:\Python27\lib\smtplib.py` in a text editor and check.

I can't tell you how this could have happened, but probably it would be best to reinstall python in this case.

Comment: In the windows case only repairing Python may not be enough. Remove it and reinstall it.